# Where to keep the response of web services?

Tags: java, web-services

I send request to web services and receive the results, then I need to allow users to sort the results. My question is that after retrieving the results where should I keep them to be able to sort them upon user's request without sending a new request using web services?

Comment: I suggest in memory or on disk.

Comment: which specific framework are you using.

Comment: This really depends on the amount of data and the type of client.

Comment: You can store the results in a database by request , that way the user can fire or refresh the requests or browse old requests.

Comment: @vikeng21 I am using Struts2

Comment: @Leon lets say I parse the results into object and it becomes 50 objects each with 10 fields.

Comment: @KennethClark that way I would need a large database, imagine 10 users request for 10 different things then it would be 100 unwanted records on db.

Comment: You can implement a policy to `archive` the data or even purge after time. If you need to store the data In memory database or standard transactional db .. if you are worried about size you will have to do a proof of concept on a couple solution and project costings. Until then size is not an issue. The costing will have to include the web service cost in terms of time and data and database physical storage cost.

Answer (score 1):

why again sending the request to web services i think no need of sending of request again once you received the result just store them in the type what ever they are and sort it mean while and get displayed to the users

Comment: i guess this is what he is asking in the first place. please be specific

Comment: The question is that where should I keep them?

Comment: you need to retrieve those response from xml and using Jquery you can make a call to function and pass those values and there you sort and display in your front end template only

Comment: do you have a sample for that?

Comment: right now i don't have it but if you are familiar with JQuery you can able to do it Please is there in one in queue to help out @Jack using the above idea absolutely it is possible using that

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Let the server sort the results before returning them to the user.
2. Give the client the capability to sort the results on the client side without having to make another web service call.

Comment: the question is that how to sort them in front-end without sending new requests to server?

Comment: I'd write a JavaScript function.

Comment: and they you would sort them using javascript or you would send a sort request to server? do you have a sample for that?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, so there'd be no need to go back to the server.  It'd be easiest if your service call was REST and sent back a JSON array.  I'm envisioning a table or grid on the client where a user could click on the column and the JavaScript function would respond to the event by sorting the rows.  No samples, sorry.  My first thought would be a grid control that could do it for me.  Try jQuery UI.

Comment: so it would keep the JSON result and sort that?

Comment: Yes, that's how I think it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky as there are several choices and you should use the one, depending on your need. You can store the data temporarily in cache or cookie if you don't require any permanent storage. Otherwise, you can use memory or database.

You can also check this link:

http://blog.mafr.de/2009/01/04/session-data-in-webapps/

It highlights some possible solutions.

Comment: I parse the results into objects so it is impossible to put them in cookie because of their size.

Comment: Then you have done with the major work. You can easily store them in xml. You can use Jaxb for that, for easy marshalling and unmarshalling. Jaxb xml parser converts any java object to xml and vice versa. Its also preety fast.

Comment: do you have a sample for that?

Comment: Just follow this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html Once you will finish this tutorial, you will be able to easily convert java object to xml and vice versa.